# Why does hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA depend on hibernate-3.2.6.ga?

Tags: java, hibernate

In my Maven pom.xml I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
```

If I look at the Maven dependencies I find that hibernate-entitymanager depends on hibernate-3.2.6.ga.

Is this correct? Why would it not depend on a 3.3.x version of Hibernate? Does this mean I am using a hybrid 3.2/3.3 version of Hibernate?

Also, I am pulling my dependencies from `repo1.maven.org` -- should I instead be using `repository.jboss.org`? For example, `repository.jboss.org` has a newer version of `hibernate-validator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions of the hibernate components are to a large degree independent of one another. v3.x of component A doesn't necessarily go with v3.x of component B.

[This link](https://www.hibernate.org/6.html#A3) shows the dependencies between the various components. This confirms that Entity Manager 3.3.2 has a dependency of 3.2.x of Hibernate Core. If you want to use Hibernate Core 3.3.x, you need to use Entity Manager 3.4.0.